# Texture going out of scope in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Well, I'm trying to make a menu using SFML 2.1. I have a 'something.h' header file and two source files. For the buttons, I've created a texture file.  Now, since I want all the menu buttons to have the same texture, I was trying to declare the texture globally. I tried a couple of ways to do this. I tried to declare it just before all the class declarations in something.h, but I found out that you can't use *texture.loadFromFile("blahblah")* without a function. SO, I decided to make a class for this, and the following is the code.

Something.h

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<iostream>
class Textureinitialize
{
public:
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Font font;
    void loadtexture(const std::string& texturestring);       //Specify file-name of texture
    void loadfont(const std::string& fontstring);             //Specify file-name of font
};
class Menubutton
{
public:
    sf::Sprite menubuttonsprite;
    sf::Text menubuttontext;
    sf::Vector2i spritekaposition;
    void loadthesprite(Textureinitialize obj1);               //Load sprite from Texture and Text from font
    void loadtexturepos(sf::IntRect rect1);                   //Load the sprite rectangle from the Texture
    void spriteposition(sf::Vector2i originpos);              //Specify position of button on the screen
    void texttodisplay(std::string displaystring);            //String to be displayed in button
    void positionoftext(sf::Vector2i textpos,int textsize);   //Set position and size of text to be displayed
};
```

This gave no error, but the menu button sprite does not display on the screen. I think the problem is with the loading of the texture. I looked around, and found that somehow the texture is going out of scope. Please could anyone help me?

EDIT:
I guess more code is the need of the hour. Here are the contents of the two source files I mentioned.

Something.cpp

```
#include "Menudata.h"
void Textureinitialize::loadtexture(const std::string& texturestring)
{
    if(!texture.loadFromFile(texturestring))
        std::cout<<"\nFailed to load textures";
}
void Textureinitialize::loadfont(const std::string& fontstring)
{
    if(!font.loadFromFile(fontstring))
        std::cout<<"\nFailed to load font";
}
void Menubutton::loadthesprite(Textureinitialize obj1)
{
        menubuttonsprite.setTexture(obj1.texture);
        menubuttontext.setFont(obj1.font);
}
void Menubutton::spriteposition(sf::Vector2i originpos)
{
    spritekaposition.x=originpos.x;
    spritekaposition.y=originpos.y;
    menubuttonsprite.setPosition(originpos.x,originpos.y);
}
void Menubutton::loadtexturepos(sf::IntRect rect1)
{
    menubuttonsprite.setTextureRect(rect1);
}
void Menubutton::texttodisplay(std::string displaystring)
{
    menubuttontext.setString(displaystring);
}
void Menubutton::positionoftext(sf::Vector2i textpos,int textsize)
{
    menubuttontext.setPosition(spritekaposition.x+textpos.x,spritekaposition.y+textpos.y);
    menubuttontext.setCharacterSize(textsize);
    menubuttontext.setColor(sf::Color::Red);
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Menudata.h"
int main()
{
    Textureinitialize a;
    a.loadtexture("Menubutton.tga");
    a.loadfont("arial.ttf");
    Menubutton b;
    b.loadthesprite(a);
    b.loadtexturepos(sf::IntRect(0,0,80,48));
    b.spriteposition(sf::Vector2i(50,50));
    b.texttodisplay("Hello!");
    b.positionoftext(sf::Vector2i(50,14),20);
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200,200),"My Window");
    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type==sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
            if(event.type==sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
            {
                b.loadtexturepos(sf::IntRect(0,48,80,48));
                if(event.mouseButton.button==sf::Mouse::Left)
                    std::cout<<"\nHello!!!";
            }
            if(event.type==sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased)
                b.loadtexturepos(sf::IntRect(0,0,80,48));
        }
        window.clear(sf::Color::Green);
        window.draw(b.menubuttonsprite);
        window.draw(b.menubuttontext);
        window.display();
    }
return 0;
}
```

The reason I thought the texture is going out of scope was that I read somewhere on Google that if you're getting a white rectangle instead of the image, you might have the said issue. Also, I just noticed that I couldn't see any text in the white box. I do have a function which displays text on the buttons in the class 'Menubutton'. I think the problem might be in the initialization of font. I hope what I've done in the class 'Textureinitialize' isn't wrong. I guess the problem might lie there.

Comment: Simply ensure your scope extends to as long you need the texture.

Comment: Without posting more code there is not much that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

As far as managing SFML resources goes, e.g. textures, I can only recommend this template:

https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML-Game-Development-Book/tree/master/02_Resources/Include/Book

This is a, in my opionion, simple way to access the texture whenever you need it to construct your buttons

P.S.: To improve readability of your code, I suggest using notations such as my_function or myFunction, instead of myfunction (all lowercase).

Comment: This *might* answer the question. Include relevant part of what you link to. In worst case links go dead, and in any case, answers are better when they survive by them self. Use links as reference is good, but always ask yourself: *"Can your post stand on its own, or does it require clicking the link to be meaningful?"*

Comment: Do not use links that can become obsolete. Spell/grammar check your posts.